# Reverse a non-editable string without using swap function

Tags: algorithm

I have been recently doing some interview questions, and I came across this question ::

> Reverse a string word by word **in place without using the swap
>   function**. The string in **not-editable**.

Source :: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adobe-interview-experience/ (6th Round, (b) part)

Is that even possible?? Reversing a non-editable string?? In any language??! :\

Thanks!

Comment: probably a trick question *Reverse a string "word by word in place without using swap function. The string is non-editable"*

Comment: I missed the `non-editable` part.  But if you can edit the string in question, then a Java `StringBuilder` will do the trick.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah thanks! :) But that `non-editable` is anyway still there.. :\

Comment: @user007 Well, in the question the job-applicant mentions :: *This question was tricky as he kept building the question with constraints. But I really enjoyed it* Doesn't look like that was the trick..

Comment: You can't edit a "not-editable" string **in-place**. In-place means to reuse the memory already allocated to the object, if you can' edit it, that's not possible.

Comment: Given "hi there" as input, do they want "there hi" or "ereht ih" for the answer? When they say "word by word in place" it makes me think they want "there hi" ... in an interview I would seek that clarification. Then either way is quite trivial: for "ereht ih" just loop over the characters in reverse order outputting them; for "there hi" also loop in reverse order appending characters to a temp var, and output (in reverse) then clear the temp var every time you hit a space (or ay beginning of original string).

Comment: @coderzz027 lol, the string is non-editable and you have to reverse it with in place algorithm.

Comment: @Sumeet irony of a question :P lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that I think is possible is ::

> Reverse a string **"word by word in place without using the swap
>   function. The string in not-editable."**

You cannot edit a non-editable string anyway!

Comment: I think that is the only thing we can do!